# problem installing ros indigo on Debian:wheezy

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install ROS indigo from source like this Tutorial [ROS indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source) and i added some different package from source and all my package are in src folder. When i execute:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y -r --os=debian:wheezy
```

i become this error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
image_geometry: No definition of [python-opencv] for OS [debian]

roslisp: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]

image_proc: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS [debian]

image_view: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS [debian]

rosconsole_bridge: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]

image_rotate: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS [debian]

rosbag_storage: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]

stereo_image_proc: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS [debian]

cpp_common: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]

cv_bridge: No definition of [python-opencv] for OS [debian]

camera_calibration: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS [debian]

tf2: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191192/problem-installing-ros-indigo-on-debian:wheezy/) by [Lil Kmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20079/lil-kmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've added the dependency definitions to the rosdep rules, so you should be able to properly use rodep for the Debian source install.  Note that as of 10/2014, `libconsole-bridge-dev` hasn't made it yet to wheezy, only jessie, so it needs to be installed from source if using wheezy.

I've made installation instructions for a RaspberryPi which uses a version of wheezy, so [these instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi#Dependencies_not_available_in_the_Raspbian_stable_branch) should work on any version of Debian to install `libconsole-bridge-dev` from source.

---

Originally posted by [awilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4577/awilson/) with karma: 231 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lil Kmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20079/lil-kmer/) on 2014-10-21**:
thank u very much.